# Add user note in CiviCRM on behalf membership page

Tags: civicrm

I have a CiviCRM contribution page form that is :

- on behalf of an organisation (required)
- used for becoming a member

I need to add the possibility for the member to add a comment on the subscription form.

I tried 2 ways that seems not to work because of current limitations :

- adding a custom field for contribution in the profile - doesn't work because of https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15787
- adding the note field in the profile - doesn't work because the note displayed in the receipt is not always the one added by the user.

I need a quick way to fix this while those bugs are resolved. 
My guess is maybe to remove the note from the receipt to avoid problems but how could i do that ?

Any better way of doing this is welcome. 
webform is excluded because i am using paypal with redirection for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a PR has been submitted regarding this issue.
Please refer here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/4884

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by using a CiviCRM integrated webform (using the webform CiviCRM integration module) and the CiviCRM contribution page. Use the webform to collect some of the information, including your comments field, and then on submission of that form take the user to the contribution page where they can initiate the transaction. Its less than ideal, but it works.

Work is going on to enable payment processors like Paypal website payments standard to work with webform_civicrm, but it's not ready yet, so I use this approach whilst awaiting that feature to be launched.